# Issue in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Getting problem in MongoDb query

```
myCollection.find({}).limit(50K)
```

return 50k documents

```
 myCollection.find({}).sort({"age" : -1}).limit(50K)
```

return 1k documents

Will you please provide solution?

Comment: If the answer by Камилов Тимур doesn't solver your problem, is there any chance the query is timing out ? Did you add a reverse index to age ?

Comment: Edited code block and added some relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but did you try to set 50000 as an argument of `.limit()`?
Like this: `.limit(50000)`.
Or try to `.limit()`, then `.sort()` your collection.

```
myCollection.find({}).limit(50000).sort({'age' : -1})
```

Comment: but i have get top 50K docs. If first i select 50k docs and then apply order is not correct way.  I want output  is  50000 docs with age having desc order

Comment: Are you sure that age has a numeric type? Or it is a string... please check it too